# Any point in refactoring RoleInterface use to Role at this point?

Tags: php, symfony

Just noticed a deprecation warning when upgrading to Symfony 3.3, that `RoleInterface` is now deprecated, and I should extend a `Role` class instead.

Reading some of [the comments about this on GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20824), however, it seems both options will be deprecated once 3.4 rolls around, and removed in 4.0. (In favor of using simple strings as roles.)

So, I have to wonder, why should anybody bother making this change, when both options basically do the same thing, and both will likely exist until both are removed? What's the point?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [Role](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Role/Role.php) vs. [RoleInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.3/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Role/RoleInterface.php#L22) you will see that Role is not deprecated, neither in branch 3.3, 3.4 nor master. This means as of now this class is not scheduled to be removed in Symfony 4. This indicates to me that the discussion ended in an agreement that Role will stay.

Long story short: Role, unlike RoleInterface, is not deprecated and will not be removed any time soon. It is absolutely safe to use.

*edit:* I just noticed [PR #22048](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/22048). So it seems I was wrong and Role might be deprecated in 3.4. Nevertheless it's probably still a good idea to extend Role for now until it's clear how to migrate from there.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question though. Sure, if I am writing new code, using the "less deprecated" version makes sense, but if I've already got code using RoleInterface, following the advice of the deprecation warning and rewriting it to use Role seems entirely pointless. Both do the same thing, and both are to be removed at the same time.

Comment: Well, it really depends on your priority and how much the deprecation warning bothers you. The current migration path is to use Role instead of RoleInterface. If later Role gets removed as well, which as of now is not 100% certain, you have to refactor again. So, yes it is valid to wait and do it in one step. It really depends on your process and your priorities. Does that answer your question? It's a minor change so I would fix this right away so I can use 3.3 with as few deprecation warnings as possible and then do the other change in 3.4 before migrating to 4.0

Comment: Why on earth would they deprecate the Interface, and force you to use their concrete class? That's madness imho.

Comment: Why is that a problem?